# Xpath select multiple tags

Tags: php, xpath

I want so multiple tags (td and th) using a PHP DOMXPath query.

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you read the manual for DOMXPath? http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `|` (Union) operator. Here is an example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<table>
<tr>
<th>table header</th>
<td>table cell</td>
</tr>
</table>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$rows = $xpath->query('//tr');                        // select all <tr> elements anywhere in the document
$cols = $xpath->query('./th | ./td', $rows->item(0)); // select all <th>/<td> from context
                                                      // where context = first row
echo $cols->length;             // 2
echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue; // table header
echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue; // table cell
```