# CURL : Get elements by class name

Tags: php, dom, curl

Here is what I have through DOM (I've removed content) :

```
    <ul class="toggle-block">
        <li>
            <h4 class="chip ui-header rounded-5 act-select toggle-active" ></h4>
            <div class="inner rounded-5 act-block">
                <div class="inlineBlock"></div>
                <div class="inlineBlock"></div>
                <div></div>
                <h5></h5>
                <div class="inlineBlock"></div>
                <div class="inlineBlock"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I need to get each content located in each **div** and **h5** from ***act-block*** main div.

I've started with this code :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$els = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="toggle-block"]/li/div');
```

But now I don't know what to do. Any idea ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I've made a test with this and it's working for the first node...

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$actblock = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' act-block ')]");
$els = $xpath->query('./div | ./h5', $actblock->item(0));
$el = $els->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $el;
```

...but it's not working for the following ones :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$actblock = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' act-block ')]");
$els = $xpath->query('./div | ./h5', $actblock->item(0));
$el = $els->item(1)->nodeValue;
echo $el;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```
$actblock = $xpath->query("//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' act-block ')]");
$els = $xpath->query('./div | ./h5', $actblock->item(0));
```

See: http://pivotallabs.com/xpath-css-class-matching/, [Xpath select multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611289/xpath-select-multiple-tags)

Comment: I tried your solution. For the first node it's OK, but not the following ones. I've edited my post.

Comment: @SergentPepper What do you mean "For the first node it's OK"? In my example I'm assuming there's only one div with class `act-block`, is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, there is only one act-block. About nodes, I meant each div/h5 inside act-block : $els->item(0)->nodeValue, $els->item(1)->nodeValue, $els->item(2)->nodeValue, etc.

Comment: @SergentPepper It works fine at me. Instead of echoing the node value try:  `var_dump($els->item(1));`

Comment: How can I send you the URL on which I made test ?

Comment: @SergentPepper Per comment. You can delete it afterwards, if you don't want to share it with the whole world.

Comment: @SergentPepper The problem is something different. The website is using javascript to populate the divs you want the content from. You'll have to find a way to run this js first before getting the contents of the div.

Comment: in the URL I gave you, it seems, the content is fully loaded. Maybe it's when you click on the left menu list it loads the content through js.

Comment: @SergentPepper Yes, you are right. I've no idea what the real problem is.

Comment: It seems when you get the div with the javascript inside, it crashes the request at some point. Is there a way to make a request and specify what to ignore for instance ?